# Converting png / jpg images to svs / tif image format

Tags: image, tiff, image-conversion, openseadragon, openslide

How can I convert png or jpg image files to svs or tif Aperio image formats? It can be in python, c++, c# or java.
Is there any library that support tif or svs format?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with any seadragons, aperios or svses, but if you want to convert JPEG or PNG to TIFF, you can use **ImageMagick** at the commandline or go to Python and use **PIL**, or **Wand**, or **pyvips** or **OpenCV**.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Setchell. OpenSlide-python does not support converting JPEG or PNG to SVS or TIF, but can open tiff. So I will use TIFF fomat

Comment: If you want to try **ImageMagick** in your Terminal/commandline, it'd just be `magick INPUT.PNG OUTPUT.TIF` or maybe with some lossless compression if they are big `magick INPUT.PNG -compress LZW OUTPUT.TIF`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this conversion is impossible since SVS constitutes a proprietary format. Openslide implements the logic to read SVS streams, but the same is not true for writing them as the specification is not open-source.
A possible workaround can be found in [this](http://www.andrewjanowczyk.com/converting-an-existing-image-into-an-openslide-compatible-format/) blog post which explains how to write an image with the minimum set of attributes that the Openslide reader method expects to sucessfully execute.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use libvips too!